# How do i keep a record/count how many people visit my site?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, count, global

Hi every one I have simple web app published on Internet [Click to see](http://sman.somee.com/) that count the number of visitors and it's work fine with that but the problem is the counter is keep reset to default NO.0 I want the counter to keep it's value without reset and my code in Global.asax is

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
```

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application startup
    ' Code that runs on application startup
    Application("SiteVisitedCounter") = 5000

    'to check how many users have currently opened our site write the following line
    Application("OnlineUserCounter") = 0

End Sub

Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application shutdown
End Sub

Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
End Sub

Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when a new session is started
    Application.Lock()
    Application("SiteVisitedCounter") = Convert.ToInt32(Application("SiteVisitedCounter")) + 1
    'to check how many users have currently opened our site write the following line
    Application("OnlineUserCounter") = Convert.ToInt32(Application("OnlineUserCounter")) + 1
    Application.UnLock()


End Sub

Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs when a session ends. 
    ' Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
    ' is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
    ' or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
    Application.Lock()
    Application("OnlineUserCounter") = Convert.ToInt32(Application("OnlineUserCounter")) - 1
    Application.UnLock()

End Sub
```

and In the Code Behind is

```
    Label3.Text = Application("SiteVisitedCounter").ToString()
    Label4.Text = Application("OnlineUserCounter").ToString()
```

Comment: just use google analytics for this, no need to do any kind of special code or whatnot. it will give you decent information on every page, where they come from, what device they use to browse the site, pretty much anything you could possibly need.

Comment: thanks for ur answer but i don't wanna use google analytics is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: When the AppPool stops (usually after 20 minutes of inactivity) or is recycled you will lose all data stored in Session and Application. If you want to track the hits you will have to log them into a database or write a file on the server with the visitor count.

Comment: @VDWWD how can i create that file and display it counter on my web any idea thanx..

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.google.nl/?gws_rd=ssl#q=read+write+file+vb.net

Comment: OK my Friend thanks I will do my best